# Why my condition format hi-light wrong rows when check 2 values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image: =AND($F2="ST",$O2>87)]

I would like to hi-light row that position contain ST and dribbling > 87.

```
=AND($F2="ST",$O2>87)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've marked the header row too, you need to use:

```
=AND($F1="ST",$O1>87)
```

Otherwise, the *next* row is highlighted.

Alternatively, just exclude the header row from your selection and use your original formula.

Comment: Good catch! It was difficult to tell from that image whether row was included or not.